# Is it possible to assign multiple has_many ":as" polymorphic relation on same field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many-polymorphs

Having my db setup like this ("type" is always User although I have different kind of User via STI):

```
class User 
  # fields
  # :id
  # :sender_id, :sender_type
  # :recipient_id, :recipient_type
end
```

Postcard model:

```
class Postcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => User
  belongs_to :recipient, :class_name => User
end
```

I'd like to setup the User model something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postcards, :as => [:sender or :recipient] # this is not working
end
```

So I could say:

```
user.postcards
```

Is it possible?

PS: I've also tried this road:

```
  has_many :postcards, :finder_sql => Proc.new { "SELECT * FROM postcards WHERE postcards.owner_id=#{id} OR postcards.recipient_id=#{id}" }
```

But found myself stuck on scopes as :finder_sql recreates a whole new SQL:

```
  User.postcards.by_status('new').size
```

Comment: Rails polymorphic associations typically are different than you're writing.

To do your Sender or Receiver, you would typically create a class that works for both such as:

class Postcard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mailable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Sender < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postcards, :as => :mailable
end

class Receiver < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :postcards, :as => :mailable
end

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I have multiple User types for example: Doctor < User and Patient < User. Being each User either a Sender or a Receiver I think final code would be unreadable/unusable. Am I right?

Comment: Depends on how you set it up. In general Rails STI (Single Table Inheritance) works pretty well for classes with large overlap IMHO; a more advanced way to set up your classes is by changing from inheritance to associations (so a Doctor has_one User) or to DCI (Data Context Integration) which makes Doctor and Patient two "roles" that a user can mix in at runtime. There's also a way to do double-sided polymorphic joins-- try searching for an older gem by Evan Weaver that does it, and see if it's maintained or has a successor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by joelparkerhenderson I need to think differently my association strategy.

As I'd like to have:

```
user.postcards
```

My answer is simply to use scopes in Postcard model:

```
scope :of_user, lambda { |user| where("recipient_id = ? OR owner_id = ?", user.id, user.id) }
```

So I can invoke:

```
Postcard.of_user user
```

I could even wrap it in User model:

```
def postcards
   Postcard.of_user self
end
```